# How to connect routes that start with custom elements?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I want to place a named parameter before the controller/action and everything else that comes after...

e.g:

```
domain.com/named_parameter/controller
domain.com/named_parameter/controller/action
domain.com/named_parameter/controller/action?key=val
domain.com/named_parameter/controller/action/other_params
```

I don't care how the rest of the URL will be structured after the `named_parameter`. I just want to place the parameter in front :)

And, I also need to make the standard URLs without the named parameter in front work.

e.g:

```
domain.com/controller
domain.com/controller/action
domain.com/controller/action?key=val
domain.com/controller/action/other_params
```

To make it simple, the named parameter will only be matched if it starts with `foo_`

e.g:

```
domain.com/foo_biz/controller/action
domain.com/foo_zip/controller/action
```

Is the matching possible? And if yes, how?

Comment: It’s difficult to ascertain what you’re trying to achieve with your abstract example. Can you give some more details as to where this would be used, and why a [prefix routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) wouldn’t be suitable?

Comment: @MartinBean We're designing an ecommerce site with multiple stores. I would like to define the scope by using the named parameter in front.

Comment: e.g: domain.com/store1/products/add  domain.com/store2/products/view

Comment: instead of having to pass the store id in every controller and action. I'll just place it in front. And use the 'persist' feature of the Router to retain that named parameter in front like for example when using the HTML helper.

Comment: So if there’s a scope of stores, why do you need it to work without the prefix? What happens if I request an action *without* a prefix; which store’s data does it load then?

Comment: There is a master account which can view data from all stores. That's the purpose of the URL without the scope

Comment: You'd probably get more help if you've ever accepted an answer, people love [fake internet points](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/09/five-years-ago-stack-overflow-launched-then-a-miracle-occurred/). Just have that in the back of your mind for future questions. ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version, we're running low on clairvoyants over here!

Comment: CakePHP version 2.3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all described in the Cookbook, see

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#connecting-routes
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements

It doesn't seem like you are atually talking about named parameters (removed as of CakePHP 3.0, so it's better to stop using them already today), as they are in `name:value` format, but simply about ordinary path components.

You can easily define your own route element and use the regex matching option to make sure the route connects only to URLs where the element starts with `foo_`. Make use of the `:controller` and `:action` elements and your routes will connect to the same controllers/actions as the ones without the `foo_` path component.

Place the routes *before* your other ones so that they take precedence and you should be good.

```
$options  = array(
    'store' => 'foo_[^\/]+', // matches everything that starts with `foo_`
    'persist' => array('store')
);

/**
 * Connects:
 *
 * /foo_storename/controller/action
 * /foo_storename/controller/action/whatever/etc...
 * /foo_storename/controller/action?bar=baz&etc...
 */
Router::connect(
    '/:store/:controller/:action/*',
    array(),
    $options
);

/**
 * Connects:
 *
 * /foo_storename/controller
 * /foo_storename/controller?bar=baz&etc...
 */
Router::connect(
    '/:store/:controller',
    array('action' => 'index'),
    $options
);

/**
 * Connects:
 *
 * /foo_storename
 * /foo_storename?bar=baz&etc...
 */
Router::connect(
    '/:store',
    array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'),
    $options
);
```

`store` is then accessible on the request object in your controllers, magically as a property of the request object:

```
$this->request->store;
```

or explicitly in the `params` property:

```
$this->request->params['store'];
```